# add click on ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I am working on a college project and have a gridview that I have to add more rows to.
I have two text fields and a button.
Everything seems to be fine except the button part of the code in the .cs file
What am I doing wring?

Its to make a list of Wines with an ID and a Title and a Year:

Wine.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Wine.aspx.cs" Inherits="WineNotProject2.AdminPages.Wine" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <br /><br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" />

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


<p><asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Wine Title"></asp:Label><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Width="176px"></asp:TextBox><br />

<p><asp:Label ID="lblYear" runat="server" Text="Wine Year"></asp:Label><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtYear" runat="server" Width="176px"></asp:TextBox><br />
</p>


<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Wine" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [Title], [Year] FROM [Wine]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


</asp:Content>
```

Wine.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WineNotProject2.AdminPages
{
    public partial class Wine : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private WineEntities10 ent2 = new WineEntities10();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                RefreshGrid();
            }
        }
            private void RefreshGrid()
            {
                GridView2.DataSource = ent2.Wines.ToList();
                GridView2.DataBind();
            }
            protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Wine w2 = new Wine();
                w2.Title = txtTitle.Text;
                w2.Year = txtYear.Text;
                ent2.Wines.AddObject(w2);
                ent2.SaveChanges();

            }

        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

The error message is:

Error   3   'WineNotProject2.AdminPages.Wine' does not contain a definition for 'Year' and no extension method 'Year' accepting a first argument of type 'WineNotProject2.AdminPages.Wine' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WineNotProject7\WineNotProject2\AdminPages\Wine.aspx.cs  30  20  WineNotProject2

Comment: Don't you need to call RefreshGrid in btnAdd_Click?

Comment: No I dont have to. But that way I can see if the button click added the info? Do you think it will work if I leave it out?

Comment: My problem seems to be at:
w2.Year = txtYear.Text;
ent2.Wines.AddObject(w2);

Comment: Why don't you need to tell the grid that the source has changed? Why do you think that the problem(what problem at all?) is at `ent2.Wines.AddObject`? You have to clarify your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have two classes with same name **Wine**.

`public partial class **Wine** : System.Web.UI.Page`

`**Wine** w2 = new **Wine**();`

Rename ASP.Net page's name to ***WineList*** so that

its class name should become `public partial class **WineList**`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call `RefreshGrid` after you have added the new Wine:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Wine w2 = new Wine();
    w2.Title = txtTitle.Text;
    w2.Year = txtYear.Text;
    ent2.Wines.AddObject(w2);
    ent2.SaveChanges();
    RefreshGrid(); // <-------
}
```

Maybe you also need to parse the year to `int`:

```
w2.Year = int.Parse(txtYear.Text);
```

Comment: I will try but the problem is not with the refresh, but with the fact that the btnAdd doesn't even see the w2.Year  from the wine.aspx page Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Visual Studio gives me an error: Does not contain a definition for Year.
Sorry for not being clear enough. New at this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was looking good ,But you miss call the RefreshGrid() end of add button

for

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Wine w2 = new Wine();
                w2.Title = txtTitle.Text;
                w2.Year = txtYear.Text;
                ent2.Wines.AddObject(w2);
                ent2.SaveChanges();
                **RefreshGrid**

            }
```

If `ent2.SaveChanges()`; is not working ,then use `ent2.SubmitChanges();`